# MERN Stack Admin Panel Multiple API Call

Tags: node.js, react-native, api, express, mern

I have been working on a MERN project where I have few Models(User, Post, Report, Message, Help). Now, I want to show those Model data on the admin panel like the number of Users, Posts, Reports, Help. For this, I need to make multiple API calls that make the whole process much slower. So any suggestions on how do I make it faster??

Answer (score 0):

As you have few Models(User, Post, Report, Message, Help) and you wanted to render it faster.

We can have 2 implantations to make it faster.

1. Create a service which should return you an object which is consolidation of all models((User, Post, Report, Message, Help).
2. Render data in chunks instead of rendering it in one go. You can do lazy loading mechanism in order to render it on user requests. This is ideal way to fetch large amount of data in UI.

I believe combining above two implementation works for you.

Happy Coding!